# Jlibfprint cross compilation

Tags: java, c++, linux, cross-compiling, buildroot

I'm trying to cross-compile the JNI Bridge Jlibfprint using buildroot.

[This](https://github.com/eduardobogoni/jlibfprint) is the source code.

Here is the .mk file:

```
JLIBFPRINT_VERSION = 775295f08174d11d39da9e327120b128ef270fc4
JLIBFPRINT_SITE = $(call github,eduardobogoni,jlibfprint,$(JLIBFPRINT_VERSION))
JLIBFPRINT_AUTORECONF = YES

JLIBFPRINT_SUBDIR = JlibFprint_jni
#JLIBFPRINT_CONF_OPTS = --enable-debug-log --enable-udev-rules=no --disable-debug-log

JLIBFPRINT_INSTALL_STAGING = YES

define PREPARE_FILES_AND_FIX_DIRECTORY
    cd $(@D)/JlibFprint_jni && \
    libtoolize
endef

JLIBFPRINT_PRE_CONFIGURE_HOOKS += PREPARE_FILES_AND_FIX_DIRECTORY

$(eval $(autotools-package))
```

Extract, Patch, Update, Configure, Autoreconfiguring, Patching libtool run without problem.

Then it failed at Building stage with this:

```
libfprint_jni_la-jlibfprint_JlibFprint.o
In file included from jlibfprint_Device.cpp:1:0:
jlibfprint_Device.h:5:10: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Then I added, these includes to the /JlibFprint_jni/src/Makefile.am

```
ADD_INCLUDES=-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -I/home/mariano/buildroot/output/build/libfprint-0.7.0 -I/home/mariano/buildroot/output/build/libfprint-0.7.0/libfprint/nbis/include
```

And now it fails with:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: ERROR: unsafe header/library path used in cross-compilation: '-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include'
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: ERROR: unsafe header/library path used in cross-compilation: '-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include'
libtool: compile:  /home/mariano/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"libfprint_jni\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"libfprint_jni\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"libfprint_jni 1.0\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"libfprint_jni\" -DVERSION=\"1.0\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING=1 -DHAVE_IOSTREAM=1 -DHAVE_LIBFPRINT_FPRINT_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -I. -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -I/home/mariano/buildroot/output/build/libfprint-0.7.0 -I/home/mariano/buildroot/output/build/libfprint-0.7.0/libfprint/nbis/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Os -c jlibfprint_JlibFprint.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libfprint_jni_la-jlibfprint_JlibFprint.o
Makefile:496: recipe for target 'libfprint_jni_la-jlibfprint_Device.lo' failed
```

Comment: Please show your jlibfprint.mk file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded JDK for ARM 32 bits and addded the includes into that folder.

I removed the BR2_COMPILER_PARANOID_UNSAFE_PATH=n as Arnout said it was wrong. And it cross-compiled without issues.

I ran the Sample Run and it worked with an Upek fingerprint scanner.

Comment: This is very wrong. The warning is there for a reason. With Buildroot, you are building for a "target" system that is different from the "host" system that you are building on. The include files from the host (i.e. /usr/include/...) are possibly different from what the libraries installed on your target expect.

Comment: Don't you think I can add the includes from a JDK for ARM? 
My target does not have a jdk installed.

Comment: If your target doesn't have JDK, then how can jlibfprint ever work on the target?

Comment: My target does have a JDK is just Buildroot that doesn't have one by default but one can download the JDK for ARM 32 and 64 bits from Oracle official page. I also do not need the JDK installed on my target but I do need it on my host, my guess is that Jlibfprint only needs some files of the JDK in order to compile the library. Which is exactly what I've done.

Answer (score 0):

Jlibfprint requires a JDK, but Buildroot doesn't have a JDK package. Therefore, building Jlibfprint using Buildroot will never work.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on this now. Buildroot includes openjdk, but does not install the jni header files, so when using staging as sysroot for cross compilation, things go wrong.

As far as I can tell the jni headers (jni.h and jni_md.h) serve as type translations only and can be included without problem for the target. I added them to the sysroot and compiling works without issues.